# How to change view of the variables when debugging in VSCode C++

Tags: visual-studio-code, variables, debugging, format, output

In my VisualStudio Code Program when debugging
I see my Variables like this

[image]

But I want to see my Variables like this

[image]

**How can I change the view of Variables in VS Code ?**

Comment: what's the actual data type in the second screenshot?

Comment: vector<string>msg. It`s the exact same code I copied from the hello World tutorial

Answer (score 0):

add this to your gdb launch config

```json
    {
      "name": "g++.exe - Build and debug active file",
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "request": "launch",
.....
      "setupCommands": [
        {
          "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
          "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
          "ignoreFailures": true
        }
      ]
    }
```